# svn and rST format project

Tags: svn, restructuredtext, pre-commit-hook

I've some problems committing a rST file like

```
=====
TITLE
=====

Chapter
=======

Section
-------

blablabla
```

I got this error:

```
Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
Some parts of your commit look suspiciously like merge
conflict markers.  Please double-check your diff and try
committing again.
```

I found that the problem are the `=` characters, probably they conflict with diff format, so I substituted all `=` with `_` and now it works, but it it ugly. Why this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Eek! My solution would be to dump SVN and use hg, but I've got a feeling that's not the sort of answer you want?

Comment: @Chris Morgan: the problem is not with SVN but with a custom hook he has that rejects code with that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that string `=========` is used in situations when there happens to be a merge conflict. One solution is to play along with pre-commit hook and use something else, like `*=========` or `===-===-===` (maybe just one space in front of the line would do), or disable that piece of code in the hook (if it's script). If the hook is an application maybe there is a configuration that you can change to disable this type of check, but I'd go with first option.

Comment: I don't want to chage the rST format and I can't change the pre-commit-hook. I was hoping there was some svn option to force the commit.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to use a hook and ignore it at the same time.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear. It's not the problem with SVN, but with the hook. Without the hook all works as expected.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I need to talk with the repository administrator

Comment: administrator says that the hook is the trigger of this regex: `grep -E '^\+(<{7} \.|={7}$|>{7} \.)'`

Comment: Yes, exactly seven characters of `=` on a line (and also cases for lines with `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>`, which are currently of no concern to you). You can avoid the problem if your line never has exactly 7 equation marks. Put one more '=', or one less, or one space after, anything that will make it different from exactly 7 '='s on a line.